# Postgresql moving data from table to 3 other tables

Tags: postgresql

I have a table:

TABLE_A

- id_table_a
- field1
- field2
- field3
- field4
- field5

I need to move the data to 3 tables, 1 parent with 2 children:

TABLE_B

- id_table_b
- id_table_a
- field1
- field2

TABLE_C

- id_table_c
- id_table_b
- field3
- field4

TABLE_D

- id_table_d
- id_table_b
- field5

We're talking about millions of registers. What would be the correct and most effective way to do this?

I'm completely new to PostgreSQL and I've come up with this after reading the documentation:

```
INSERT INTO table_b (id_table_a, field1, field2) SELECT id_table_a FROM table_a, SELECT field1 FROM table_a, SELECT field2 FROM table_a;

INSERT INTO table_c (id_table_b, field3, field4) SELECT id_table_b FROM table_b, SELECT field3 FROM table_a WHERE table_b.id_table_a = table_a.id_table_a, SELECT field4 FROM table_a WHERE table_b.id_table_a = table_a.id_table_a;

INSERT INTO table_d (id_table_d, field5) SELECT id_table_c FROM table_c, SELECT field5 FROM table_a WHERE table_b.id_table_a = table_a.id_table_a;
```

Would this do what I need or am I missing something? Thank you.

Comment: If the source of an INSERT is a SELECT, remove the `VALUES` clause: `insert into .. (..) select ... from ...`

Comment: The `SELECT` after the insert (there should only be 1 SELECT) should return all the fields that are needed to do the INSERT. No need for more than 1 SELECT statement.

Answer (score 0):

This will not work:

```
INSERT INTO table_b (id_table_a, field1, field2) SELECT id_table_a FROM table_a, SELECT field1 FROM table_a, SELECT field2 FROM table_a;
```

because the query `SELECT id_table_a FROM table_a` will (or can) return more than 1 value.

You need to write it like:

```
INSERT INTO table_b (id_table_a, field1, field2) 
   SELECT id_table_a, field1, field2 FROM table_a;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe sub-optimal but a straightforward PL/pgSQL `do` block will help. Pls. note the `returning into` clause. Assuming that `id_table_b`, `id_table_c` and `id_table_d` are autogenerated integers, then

```sql
DO language plpgsql
$$
declare
  r record;
  var_id_table_b integer;
begin
 for r in select * from table_a loop
   insert into table_b (id_table_a, field1, field2) 
     values (r.id_table_a, r.field1, r.field2) 
     RETURNING id_table_b INTO var_id_table_b;
   insert into table_c (id_table_b, field3, field4) 
     values (var_id_table_b, r.field3, r.field4);
   insert into table_d (id_table_b, field5) 
     values (var_id_table_b, r.field5);
 end loop;
end;
$$;
```